# order by dajngo queriset

Tags: python, model

*i need to order the queries set order by date_created*

class Order(models.Model):
STATUS = (
('Return', 'Return'),
('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
('new order', 'new order'),
('hold', 'hold'),

```
    )

user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True , choices=STATUS, default='new order',blank=True)
note = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True,blank=True)
receiver_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
receiver_address= models.CharField(max_length=200)
receiver_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
order_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
condition= models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
delivery_cost = models.IntegerField(default=60,null=True,blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

emphasized text

all_order = Order.objects.exclude(status='new order').order_by('order_date1')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
all_order = Order.objects.exclude(status='new order').order_by('date_created')
```

Should do what you want. Not sure where you got `'order_date1'` from but since your model field is called `'date_created'` you should order by that in the Django query. Or you can use `'-date_created'` if you want descending order (most recent date first).

Alternatively, if you always want `Order` objects to be sorted this way, just define the model's meta class as follows:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_created']
```

Then you don't have to use the `order_by()` method every time you retrieve a queryset, unless you want to order by something other than `'date_created'` for that particular queryset.